# Mongoose find.where in a schema with an attribute of type ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have this schemas:

**UserLike**

```
const UserLikeSchema = Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: [true, "User is required"],
  },
  game: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Game",
    required: [true, "Game is required"],
  }
});
```

**Game**

```
const GameSchema = Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Title is required"],
  },
  status: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
});
```

I need to find all UserLikes where populated Game.status are true

I'm trying with a code like this

```
  const games = await UserLike.find()
  .populate("game")
  .where("game.status")
  .equals(true);
```

But I can't find a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the match option as directed by mongoose docs.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions

The query might look something like this:

```js
UserLike.
  find().
  populate({
    path: 'game',
    match: { status: true },
  }).
  exec();
```

Comment: I didn't use this, because I need to paginate, and although the game don't populate, it would still bring me the UserLike record.

Comment: You should still be able to paginate using this.

Comment: But when paginating I get the records even when 'Game' is null, I want to restrict that.